# Importing a .txt Raster file

Tags: r, raster

I want to import a two raster files into R using the raster function.

One of them is an .asc file and as such had now problem.

My other file is a .txt file in what should be the same format as the .asc file (i.e. the only thing different is the file extension).

However, when I try to import the .txt file it says that it cannot produce a raster file from it. After looking I think it is that .txt files aren't supported.

Is there another function that could allow me to import a raster file or do I just have to change the file extension?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the `raster` package doc:

> filename (character), Extent, Raster*, SpatialPixels*, SpatialGrid*,
>   object, ’im- age’, matrix, im, or missing. Supported file types are
>   the ’native’ raster package format and those that can be read via
>   rgdal

I don't think that `.txt` is a valid GDAL file format.

Did you rename the `.txt` file to an `.asc` file and try it?

Comment: I tried both renaming and converting it to an .asc file.

Comment: It must be a problem with how the file has been constructed